# Android - WindowManager causing crash with "window count is over max 300"

Tags: android, kotlin

I just noticed a crash on one of my apps that seems to be happening since Android 12. I'm having trouble figuring out what caused the problem and how to fix it.
Here is the stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: window count is over max 300
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:430)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:133)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5322)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: [similar question, without answer yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72637865/android-windowmanager-causing-crash-with-window-count-is-over-max-300)

Comment: Kindly let us know if you figured it out